# Is the implementation of JavaScript's execution context an example of heap space?

Tags: javascript, heap-memory, executioncontext

Conceptually, would the data requirements as stored in memory to create an execution context in JavaScript be considered an example of heap space?

My understanding is that as frames are added to JavaScript's call stack, execution contexts are created in heap space.

Is this correct?

Comment: What implementation are you talking about? V8? Chakra?  SpiderMonkey? [Something else](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ECMAScript_engines)?

Comment: I wasn't aware that there would be differences in implementation...

Comment: Execution contexts are managed in a stack that resides in the heap.